# How to make type inference work for TypeScript generic method

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I'm trying to rewrite some C# code in TypeScript to no avail.
Response type cannot be inferred unless I supply the base class directly.

```
class CommandParameter {
  readonly value: string = "value";
}

class Command<T> {}

class SubCommand<T> extends Command<T> {}

class Client {
  execute<T>(command: Command<T>): T {
    return null as T;
  }
}
//TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
const valueError = new Client().execute(new SubCommand<CommandParameter>()).value; //<--error
const valueOk = new Client().execute(new Command<CommandParameter>()).value;
```

Is it even possible to achieve desired behavior (make inference work for sub-classes) with Typescript? May be there are any similar alternative patterns?

Comment: Your `Command` and `Subcommand` classes are structurally independent of their type parameters and indeed identical to the empty object type `{}`.  You need to fix that, as described in [the TS FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  Here's one possible approach: [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKpX8w). Does that fully address the question? If so I 'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, yes, this answers my question, and thank you for the link with the explanation, of how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is largely [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  Types are compared by their shapes/structures and not by their names/declarations.  Your example classes

```
class Command<T> {}
class SubCommand<T> extends Command<T> {}
```

are structurally identical to each other and to the empty [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types), and structurally independent of their [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  So `Command<string>` and `SubCommand<number>` and `Command<Date>` and `SubCommand<boolean>` are all *the same type*.

This makes inference behave poorly; sometimes that the compiler can indeed infer `T` from something like `Command<T>` by pattern-matching on the declarations, as if it had a nominal type system.  But even where that works it's incredibly fragile.  As soon as the compiler performs a structural comparison, then there's no way to infer `T` from `{}`.  This issue with inference is described in the TypeScript FAQ entry [Why doesn't type inference work on this interface: `interface Foo<T> { }`?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--)

---

The fix in general is that you make any generic type depend structurally on its generic type parameters.  For example:

```
class Command<T> {
    x;
    constructor(x: T) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

class SubCommand<T> extends Command<T> {
}
```

Now a `Command<T>` has an `x` property of type `T`, and so does a `SubCommand<T>` because it inherits from `Command<T>`.  So now these types are no longer identical to `{}`, but to `{x: T}`.  Inferring `T` from `{}` isn't possible in general, but inferring `T` from `{x: T}` is straightforward.  And now everything works:

```
const v1 = new Client().execute(new SubCommand(new CommandParameter())).value;
const v2 = new Client().execute(new Command(new CommandParameter())).value;
```

---

Obviously it's not always applicable to give a class a property whose type is the generic type parameter, but hopefully you actually deal with values of type `T` somewhere in your class so that a `Command<T>` depends structurally on `T` *somehow*.  If not then generics might not actually be what you want, or you might have to simulate nominal typing with dummy/phantom properties.  But these are out of scope for the question as asked, so I won't digress further here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99#code/FAYwNghgzlAEDCB7AtsiA7AJgBQgJwmQFMAXIvWAb2FltjyIk0XTAE9YA3CMAVyIBcsKCTwBLdAHNYAXlgAibnyLyA3MAC+wUJBgIUaLAB4AKgD4qNOgA91dWCBYi8vECUR4AFNaEmAlJb29iQAFmJQAHTWsrC2VrRaWjrQcADKvABGSKgYmKYWRNZkWHDZhnnmlkngKQhgYkToJIF0hUQgvGT5no45WEJlufl+vi1B9KS8eOgOBrlR8bCJ2o7oIlwAjDHoRADudQ1Nnn4RbR1knjv76VlzWJd7+n04+ISk5Md+J0r86qvrnAATNtHvB6o0SMdTtZ2p0iA99oN7lcnuVcARiGQvF9vjxfsAgA)